# jQuery selecting element AFTER the closest

Tags: jquery, dom

I have SharePoint code that renders a select element in a table, and I want to be able to select the `<tr>`s BELOW the select element, however, when I try to use:

`$("option").eq(1).closest("tr")...`, it selects the row that the select element is in. I'd like to be able to select the  AFTER the one that the select element is in.

The generated code looks like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <select>
       <option>...</option>
       <option>...</option> 
       <option>...</option>
     </select>
  </tr>
  <tr> <-- i want to select this row
     <input>...</input>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
     <input>...</input>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Since it is generated code, I can't use classes or IDs, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$("option").closest("tr").next('tr');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VREFL/

Comment: Thanks Jason P :) 
What would I use if I wanted the next TWO rows? I tried .next('tr') again, and it didn't seem to work